# Azure Resource graph explorer Query "Error joining 'microsoft.compute/sqlvirtualmachine' with 'microsoft.compute/disks'

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, azure-resource-graph

I am new the KQL on Azure resource graph explorer kql queries, I have a requirement to get the SQLVM with associated disk. I wrote this query and getting below error.

Any help is highly appreciated.

**Query:**

> resources
> | where type == "microsoft.sqlvirtualmachine/sqlvirtualmachines"
> | project id, vmid=properties.virtualMachineResourceId, name, img=properties.sqlImageOffer, sqlImgOffered=properties.sqlImageSku,
> sqlLicense=properties.sqlServerLicenseType | join (resources
> | where type == "microsoft.compute/disks"
> | project managedBy, diskSizeGB=properties.diskSizeGB, tier=properties.tier, diskIOPSRW=properties.diskIOPSReadWrite,
> diskMBpsReadWrite=properties.diskMBpsReadWrite, diskState=properties.diskState)
> on $left.vmid == $right.managedBy

**Output:**

Details:

> Query is invalid. Please refer to the documentation for the Azure
> Resource Graph service and fix the error before retrying.
> (Code:InvalidQuery) join key 'vmid' is of a 'dynamic' type. Please use
> an explicit cast using extend operator in the join legs (for example,
> '... | extend vmid = tostring(vmid) | join (... | extend vmid =
> tostring(vmid)) on vmid') as join on a 'dynamic' type is not
> supported. (Code:Default)

Please help in solving this error.

Answer (score 0):

Query posted in question has issue with *properties.virtualMachineResourceId* as *properties* contains Json data. When getting *virtualMachineResourceId* from *properties* *properties.virtualMachineResourceId* is evaluating as object.

I have used `tostring()` to convert the returned value to string and it worked for me.

**Below is modified query:-**

```
resources
| where type == "microsoft.sqlvirtualmachine/sqlvirtualmachines"
| project id,
//used tostring() to convert properties.virtualMachineResourceId value to string 
vmid=tostring(properties.virtualMachineResourceId), name,
 img=properties.sqlImageOffer,
 sqlImgOffered=properties.sqlImageSku,
 sqlLicense=properties.sqlServerLicenseType
| join (resources | where type == "microsoft.compute/disks"
| project managedBy,
diskSizeGB=properties.diskSizeGB,
tier=properties.tier,
diskIOPSRW=properties.diskIOPSReadWrite,diskMBpsReadWrite=properties.diskMBpsReadWrite,
diskState=properties.diskState) 
on $left.vmid == $right.managedBy
```